# How to read in c# oracle XmlType from store procedure

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ado.net, plsql, xmltype

I'm trying to create a XML in stored procedure in this way:

```
PROCEDURE DeviceSearched(
   xml_out OUT XMLTYPE
)
IS
BEGIN

    SELECT 
      XMLELEMENT("Values", 
          XMLFOREST(de_brand)
    ) 
    INTO xml_out
    FROM 
      tbldevice de 
    ;  

END DeviceSearched;
```

And I trying to read `xml_out` in c# in this way:

```
...
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(name, conn);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.BindByName = true;
...
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("xml_out", OracleDbType.XmlType, ParameterDirection.Output));
```

With this approach the issues are two:

1. Oracle exception: "ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
2. If I modify the query to obtain one row, the procedure is ok (I think), but in c# I don't have any result.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: any full source code sample about it?

Answer (score 1):

- Running
   `SELECT XMLELEMENT("Values",XMLFOREST(de_brand)) FROM tbldevice de`
  In plsql will **NOT** result a single value, So trying to fetch the result in to single variable (`INTO xml_out`) will result run time error ORA-01422
- Using a store procedure to select data in Oracle is not apperciated, its a SQL Server approch, why not using a simple select
- Examples [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/featXML.htm) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10790/xdb_odpnet.htm) will show how ODP.Net works with XML
  You may need to mix using ref corsur and XMLType to solve the matter